Access properties with a union variable whilst maintaining the type of the value relative to the key
Imagine the example below (process.env used to imply a runtime variable, ignore the cast we can assume it has been typechecked and guarantee it has the correct type):
type ActionType = 'withdraw' | 'deposit'
type Action = { type: 'withdraw'; address: string } | {
  type: 'deposit'
  address: number
}

type Encoder<T extends ActionType> = (action: Action & { type: T }) => string
type FactoryMapping = {
  [key in ActionType]?: Encoder<key>
}

const factories: FactoryMapping = {
  withdraw: action => action.address,
  deposit: action => action.address.toFixed(2),
}

const action: Action = JSON.parse(
  process.env['ACTION'] || '',
) as Action

const type = action.type
const factory = factories[type]
if (factory) {
  // Error here, action is never
  // Typescript infers is that its a merge of all possible
  // actions which is intentionally impossible
  factory(action)
}

The key aspect is that there's a relationship between the key of FactoryMapping and the value. Expectation is that when I access factories[type], this relationship is maintained, however TypeScript assumes the action is a merge of all actions (which is never because its not possible).
Is there a way to maintain this relationship, i.e. factories[type]: Encoder<typeof type> ?
since type cannot be all members of its union at the same time, it seems nonsensical that ts is resolving the return type to an intersection of all actions

If you check the type for FactoryMapping, keys correspond to Encoder where T is the type. This means getting factories[type], must have a value of Encoder. This function should then match the type of the action, therefore completing the chain.
The assume part was for parsing action and type from process.env, we can assume the cast is correct for this example case (which typescript already assumes)

my apologies I just got your point. Amended the question, the type should have been action.type not a new parameter

Great, thanks. Your issue is ms/TS#30581 and the recommended approach is ms/TS#47109. The necessary refactoring is shown here. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable dupe target; if not, what am I missing?

yes those are very close to the issue, in those examples its within the same union, this case is still correlated unions but across different objects which I assume shouldn't make a difference. You example removes type from the action object. is it possible to keep that type parameter within the object and use Extract to filter the union instead of writing it as a mapping?

I didn't remove anything, my Action type is structurally the same as yours. You can write it however you want to start with and then derive the types TS needs, as shown here; you could leave your original types completely alone and then go through the exercise to compute the types as a mapping for use by ms/TS#47109.  But you need those mapping types because that's the whole point. ms/TS#30581 isn't just very close, it's exactly your issue, and ms/TS#47109 is the only way TS has to support that, and it requires type refactoring as described within. How shall I proceed?

indeed I misread it initially. I refactored your example to use Extract here. This keep the original type and eliminates the need for writing an additional type structure for the mapping (since that'll be duplicated in my example as the action type comes from another location).
Can you give it a review and if happy would be fantastic if you are happy to post it as an answer. Thanks a lot this had me stuck for the whole day

I have to post your version of the code as an answer? I don't know why you need that. Can't you just accept the answer as offered and rewrite it however you need to fit your use case? Your question as asked doesn't care about Extract. For future readers, does that really matter?

Not really post whichever you prefer. I just offered the edited one as it didn't require the additional map but happy either way

Yeah, makes sense. I'll look at writing an answer when I get a chance. Note that if yours is simpler and still works, you might want to write an answer.

Use generics such as <T extends ActionType> and then accessing the Action<T>
It means you can create a function, for example, that would handle your facrories type identification. Take
interface Actions {
   withdraw: { address: string }
   deposit: { address: number }
}
type ActionType = keyof Actions;
type Action<K extends keyof Actions> = {
    [T in K]: { type: T } &
    Actions[T]
}[K];
type Encoder<K extends ActionType> = (action: Action<K>) => string;
type FactoryMapping = {
   [K in ActionType]?: Encoder<K>
};

const factories… // same

const action: Action<ActionType> = JSON.parse(
   process.env['ACTION'] || '',
);

const handleFactoriesActions<T extends ActionType> = (
    factories: FactoryMapping,
    action: Action<T>
) => {
    const factory = factories[action.type];
    if (!factory) return // or throw an error
    return factory(action); // or just factory(action) if it should be called directly
};

handleFactoriesActions(factories, action);


@jcalz Thanx, seems like a reasonable comment
